# How to get LiveData to switch between two other LiveData

Tags: android, kotlin, android-lifecycle

I have the following scenario. Podcasts can come from internet or local(db) both are LiveData

```
// Live
private val _live = MutableLiveData<List<Podcast>>()
val live: LiveData<List<Podcast>> = _live

// Local
val local: LiveData<List<Podcast>> = dao.observePodcasts()

// Combined
val podcasts: LiveData<List<Podcast>> = ...
```

My question is:- How can i use only one LiveData `podcasts` such that on demand I can get data from live or local

```
fun search(query: String) {
    // podcasts <- from live
}

fun subcribed() {
    // podcasts <- from local
}
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/MediatorLiveData

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `MediatorLiveData` didn't suit my needs as I expected because I wanted to be able to switch between local and live whenever I want!

So I did the implementation as follows

```
enum class Source {
    LIVE, LOCAL
}

private val _live = MutableLiveData<List<Podcast>>()
private val _local = dao.observePodcasts()
private val source = MutableLiveData<Source>(Source.LOCAL)

// Universal
val podcasts: LiveData<List<Podcasts>> = source.switchMap {
    liveData {
        when (it) {
            Source.LIVE -> emitSource(_live)
            else -> emitSource(_local)
        }
    }
}
```

> emitSource() removes the previously-added source.

Then I implemented the following two methods

```
fun goLocal() {
    source.postValue(Source.LOCAL)
}

fun goLive() {
    source.postValue(Source.LIVE)
}
```

I then call respected function whenever to observer from live or local storage

One of the usecase

```
searchItem.setOnActionExpandListener(object : MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener {
    override fun onMenuItemActionExpand(p0: MenuItem?): Boolean {
        viewModel.goLive()
        return true
    }

    override fun onMenuItemActionCollapse(p0: MenuItem?): Boolean {
         viewModel.goLocal()
         return true
    }
})
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`MediatorLiveData`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/MediatorLiveData?authuser=3) in this case.
What you need to do with `MediatorLiveData` is need the `LiveData` sources to be able to listen for changes to the `LiveData` source.

Try the following:

*YourViewModel.kt*

```
private val _podcasts = MediatorLiveData<List<Podcast>>().apply {
    addSource(_live) { dataApi ->
        // Or you can do something when `_live` has a change in value.
        if(local.value == null) {
            this.value = dataApi  
        }
    }

    addSource(local) { dataLocal ->
        // Or you can do something when `local` has a change in value.
        if(_live.value == null) {
            this.value = dataLocal
        }
    }
}
val podcasts: LiveData<List<Podcast>> = _podcasts
```

Answer (score 2):

[MediatorLiveData](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/MediatorLiveData)

I've personally used MediatorLiveData in [projects](https://github.com/jakebreen/pokecart/blob/master/app/src/main/java/uk/co/jakebreen/pokecart/model/filter/FilterRepository.kt) to achieve the same function you're describing.

As quoted directly from the docs since they are pretty straight forward...

> Consider the following scenario: we have 2 instances of LiveData, let's name them liveData1 and liveData2, and we want to merge their emissions in one object: liveDataMerger. Then, liveData1 and liveData2 will become sources for the MediatorLiveData liveDataMerger and every time onChanged callback is called for either of them, we set a new value in liveDataMerger.

```
LiveData liveData1 = ...;
LiveData liveData2 = ...;

MediatorLiveData liveDataMerger = new MediatorLiveData<>();
liveDataMerger.addSource(liveData1, value -> liveDataMerger.setValue(value));
liveDataMerger.addSource(liveData2, value -> liveDataMerger.setValue(value));
```

Answer (score 0):

As already suggested, this can be accomplished with `MediatorLiveData`. Another option would be using [Flows](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/flow) instead of combining LiveData.

```
    val podcasts = combine(local, live) { local, live ->
        // Add your implementation of how you would like to combine them
        live ?: local
    }.asLiveData(viewModelScope.coroutineContext)
```

If you're using Room, you can simply change the return type to Flow to get a Flow result. And for the MutableLiveData you can replace it with MutableStateFlow.